# How do I get a string from this kind of array?

Tags: php, json, arrays

I am using this PHP code to recieve information from my server:

```
<?php
require('JSONAPI.php');

$api = new JSONAPI("localhost", 25566, "admin", "changeme", "");

var_dump($api->call("server.version"));
?>
```

And this is what gets returned:

```
array(3) { ["result"]=> string(7) "success" ["source"]=> string(14) "server.version" ["success"]=> string(43) "git-Bukkit-1.6.4-R2.0-b2918jnks (MC: 1.6.4)" }
```

I want to be able to echo just one part in the returned array: "git-Bukkit-1.6.4-R2.0-b2918jnks (MC: 1.6.4)". Then I would like to echo this string in ANOTHER PHP file. How would I convert this part of the array to a string and echo it in another PHP file?

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with Java, but you can just include this file into another file (`include 'this_file.php';`). Save the API-call results to a variable (var_dump() just dumps it to the output) (`$results = $api->call(...);`) - now you can access it like a usual associative array: `echo $results["success"];`

Comment: Let me try that. I'll get back to you with results!

Comment: Oh... and you'll probably have to json_decode() it first: `$results = json_decode($api->call(...), true);` - This converts the Json-object into an array which makes it easier to accesss.

Comment: You're welcome :) I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just include this file into another one with `include 'file.php'`, call the API and save it to a variable and then just convert it into an associative array for better accessability:

```
<?php

include 'file.php';

$results = json_decode($api->call("server.version"), true);

echo 'Success Message: ' . $results['success'];
```